# Java regex to combine negative and positive regex

Tags: java, regex

Since in SAP Hana, "inner" keyword is a reserve keyword ,  so I'm looking for java regex to replace all the occurrences of inner keyword with a new keyword  from my Hana query leaving inner join and "as inner" untouched.

So below is my input Hana query :

```
select INNER.*, INNER.stud_id as "inner", INNER . stud_id 
from (select NVL(qs.qual_id,qr.qual_id) AS qualIDRoot,qr.stud_id, qr.qual_id as qualID
      from pa_stud_qual_relation qr,
               pa_qual_subqual qs                
         where 1 = 1
             and qs.qual_id_sub(+)=qr.qual_id
          group by qr.stud_id, qr.qual_id, NVL(qs.qual_id,qr.qual_id) 
     ) INNER
inner join pa_qual_cpnt qc on INNER.qualid=qc.qual_id
WHERE (INNER.QUALIDROOT =  INNER.QUALID or INNER.QUALID is NULL)
```

Result query should be like this :

```
select newKeyword.*, newKeyword.stud_id as **"inner"**, newKeyword . stud_id 
from (select NVL(qs.qual_id,qr.qual_id) AS qualIDRoot,qr.stud_id, qr.qual_id as qualID
      from pa_stud_qual_relation qr,
               pa_qual_subqual qs                
         where 1 = 1
             and qs.qual_id_sub(+)=qr.qual_id
          group by qr.stud_id, qr.qual_id, NVL(qs.qual_id,qr.qual_id) 
     ) newKeyword
**inner join** pa_qual_cpnt qc on newKeyword.qualid=qc.qual_id
WHERE (newKeyword.QUALIDROOT =  newKeyword.QUALID or newKeyword.QUALID is NULL) .
```

I have tried many different combination of regex but couldn't get the desired result .

```
String test = sql;

Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(\\binner\\b)[^(inner\\s+join)]", 
Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);  // To combine postive and negative regex
Matcher m = r.matcher(sql);
    while (m.find()) {
        String str = m.group(0);

        System.out.println(str);
        test = test.replace(str, "newKeyword");
    }
```

Thanks in Advance , 
Ali

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're overcomplicating things here. I mean, unless you ommitted some complexity from your example all you need is to:

```
query
.replaceAll("INNER","newKeyword") //keyword replace
.replaceAll("inner join","**innej join**") //stars around inner join
.replaceAll("\"inner\"", "**\"inner\"**") //stars around inner in quotes
```

If you can't rely on `INNER` always being uppercase in the `newKeyword` case you can replace on `inner.` and be fine on that front as well.

Comment: I know with approach we can do ,  but client requirement  states that , it need to be done in a single pattern